# mootools extend class

Tags: javascript, oop, mootools

I have this code:

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    Implements: [Options,Events],
    initialize: function(){

    },
    doStuff: function() {
        console.log('In MyClass');
    }
});


var MyBetterClass = new Class({
    Extends: MyClass,
    initialize: function() {

    },
    doExtraStuff: function() {
        console.log('In MyBetterClass');
    }        
});    

var a = new MyBetterClass();
```

When `doStuff` is called somewhere I want the doExtraStuff to get called too. How would I go about doing this? It's so I do not have to mess around with someone elses code, but when something happens in their code I want something else to happen in mine. There is no event fired in the parent class.

Comment: there are some serious syntax errors in your code, are you sure this is the same as the original?

Comment: Fixed the syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is override the doStuff method in MyBetterClass, then call the overridden method on the super class:

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    Implements: [Options,Events],
    initialize: function(){

    },
    doStuff: function() {
        console.log('In MyClass');
    }
});


var MyBetterClass = new Class({
    Extends: MyClass,
    initialize: function() {

    },
    doStuff: function() {
        this.parent();
        console.log('In MyBetterClass');
    }        
});    

var a = new MyBetterClass();
```

Comment: That's great - now, the parent method is getting passed some values, and firebug is reporting that `this.values is undefined`. Is there a way of keeping these values and not getting the error?

Comment: Without seeing the code I can't answer your question very well, but if the method is being passed any arguments, they will be passed to the override method as well.  They won't be properties on this, they will be function arguments, which can be named, or accessed through the arguments collection.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a sub-class method inside the parent class. You can override the `doStuff` method of parent class, call the parent's method through `parent` property of the subclass and then implement your own code.

**Super Class**

```
var MyClass = new Class({
    Implements: [Options,Events],
    initialize: function(){

    },
    doStuff: function() {
        console.log('In MyClass');
    }
});
```

**Sub class**

```
var MyBetterClass = new Class({
    Extends: MyClass,
    initialize: function() {

    },
    doStuff: function() {
        this.parent();
        console.log('In MyBetterClass');
        // your own implementation of this method
    }        
});
```

then

```
var a = new MyBetterClass();
a.doStuff(); // prints on console "In MyClass" and "In MyBetterClass"
```